# What tag to use for the unlicense?

Tags: support, tags

There is a tag [unlicensed-code](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unlicensed-code) though that is:

> Code which has not been published under a license and can be used only under regular copyright law.

Is there an appropriate tag to use for questions about the [unlicense](http://unlicense.org/)? Or a way to make sure people who don't read the tag excerpt (a common problem on other sites) are going to have a better than 50/50 chance of getting the right tag?

Answer (score 3):

No; the [unlicensed-code](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unlicensed-code) tag is for questions about *code*, specifically *unlicensed* code.

We have license-specific tags for many licenses, such as [gpl](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpl). If there isn't already one for the Unlicense, create it when you ask! If you don't have enough rep, ask away anyway, and someone with the necessary rep can edit it in.

Comment: It was more of a "there was a question on Programmers.SE about the unlicense and I was going to say 'check this tag on opensource'" - but when I looked at what I would expect the unlicense to be tagged as, it wasn't.

Comment: @MichaelT In that case, the answer is simply "we don't have a tag for it" - we've had no questions about it so far.

Comment: @Zizouz212 it would have to be simply "unlicense". The tag wiki and excerpt are th places to disambiguate.